# Splitting dictionary into existing columns

Tags: python, pandas, parsing, dictionary

Suppose I have the  dataframe `pd.DataFrame({'a':nan, 'b':nan, 'c':{'a':1, 'b':2},{'a':4, 'b':7, 'c':nan}, {'a':nan, 'b':nan, 'c':{'a':6, 'b':7}})`. I want to take the values from the keys in the dictionary in column `c` and parse them into keys `a` and `b`.

Expected output is:

```
   a                   b                  c
0  1                   2      {'a':1, 'b':2}
1  4                   7                 nan
2  6                   7      {'a':6, 'b':7}
```

I know how to do this to create new columns, but that is not the task I need for this, since `a` and `b` have relevant information needing updates from `c`. I have not been able to find anything relevant to this task.

Any suggestions for an efficient method would be most welcome.

** EDIT **

The real problem is that I have the following dataframe, which I reduced to the above (in several, no doubt, extraneous steps):

```
a                      b          c
0  nan                 nan        [{'a':1, 'b':2}, {'a':6, 'b':7}] 
1  4                   7          nan
```

and I need to have output, in as few steps as possible, as per

```
   a                 b        c
0  1                 2        {'a':1, 'b':2} 
1  4                 7        nan
2  6                 7        {'a':6, 'b':7}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide your expected output? I think this may be [`.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
def func(x):
    d = eval(x['c'])
    x['a'] = d['a']
    x['b'] = d['b']
    return x


df = df.apply(lambda x : func(x), axis=1)
```

Comment: I used a variant on this. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
for t in d['c'].keys():
     d[t] = d['c'][t]
```

Here is an example:

```
>>> d = {'a': '', 'b': '', 'c':{'a':1, 'b':2}}
>>> d
{'a': '', 'b': '', 'c': {'a': 1, 'b': 2}}
>>> d.keys()
dict_keys(['a', 'b', 'c'])
>>> d['c'].keys()
dict_keys(['a', 'b'])
>>> for t in d['c'].keys():
...     d[t] = d['c'][t]
... 
>>> d
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': {'a': 1, 'b': 2}}
>>>
```

We can turn it into a function:

```
>>> def updateDict(dict, sourceKey):
...     for targetKey in dict[sourceKey].keys():
...             dict[targetKey] = dict[sourceKey][targetKey]
... 
>>> d = {'a': '', 'b': '', 'c':{'a':1, 'b':2}}
>>> updateDict(d, 'c')
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': {'a': 1, 'b': 2}}
>>> d = {'a': '', 'b': '', 'c':{'a':1, 'b':2, 'z':1000}}
>>> updateDict(d, 'c')
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'z': 1000}, 'z': 1000}
>>>
```